# How to rank rows in pandas with multiple condition?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a rank column for the dataframe below.

Here column S,L,C are the index columns and IM, CL and CTR are the value columns

[image: Raw Data]

The image below is the final dataframe, lets take a look at row number 1 to 3, they all belong to the same index m,h,p here the rank will be first based on the highest CTR, since CTR is same for row 1 and 3 then the rank will be based on highest IM, so row 3 will be rank 1, row 1 will be rank 2 and row 2 will be rank 3.

Similarly all the indexes will be ranked

[image: Final Df]

How do I implement this in pandas?

I tried the group by rank method, but there I was only able to rank using one value column, and multiple rows had the same rank I dont want any two rows to have same rank, It should all be unique.

Comment: Not sure what you said, but I guess you want to copy the data? here in this sheet I have pasted the data https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nWEEpkdrrrHc_-4Kamm3LQoV2k-Ue38YMpV39-Tapps/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USE `GROUPBY`:

```
df = df.sort_values(['S','L','C','CTR','IM'], ascending=[True,True,True,False,False])
df['Rank'] = df.groupby(['S','L','C']).cumcount() + 1
```

OR:

```
df = df.convert_dtypes()
def rank_count(x):
    x = x.sort_values(['CTR','IM'], ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)
    x['Rank'] = x.index + 1
    return x
result = df.groupby(['S','L','C'], sort=False).apply(rank_count).reset_index(drop=True)
```